# Question on Polynomial Determinants (what are they?)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

For any given square invertible matrix $A \in M_n(F)$ there exists a determinant. From Wikipedia: Geometrically, [the determinant] can be viewed as the volume scaling factor of the linear transformation described by the matrix.

Conventionally, we view $F$ as a normal field over $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$. But what if we were to define a field $\mathbb{A(x)}$ whose elements are functions in the form $f(x) \div g(x)$, where $f(x), g(x)$ are both polynomials and $g(x) \neq 0$.

In this kind of field, if we were to take $B \in M_n(F)$ where $F \in \mathbb{A(x)}$, what would be the purpose of the determinant? What operation is it describing?

Comment: The purpose of the determinant is independent of the field $F$. We write $\det(A)$ for $A\in M_n(F)$ for all fields $F$. For example, the linear transformation $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det(A)\neq 0$. This holds for all fields, also for the function fields.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm asking what is the geometric meaning of a determinant for such a field? You can't scale a linear transformation by a polynomial (logically speaking).